# Maiking buttons visible in other classes

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, jbutton

I'm writing simple d&d dice manager for practice, and I'm wondering how can i access my buttons outside of their own class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

class Buttoner extends JPanel{
public JButton d4, d6, d8, d12, d20, d100;
Buttoner(){
    this.add(d4 = new JButton("d4"));
    this.add(d6 = new JButton("d6"));
    this.add(d8 = new JButton("d8"));
    this.add(d12 = new JButton("d12"));
    this.add(d20 = new JButton("d20"));
    this.add(d100 = new JButton("d100"));
}
}

class Framer extends JFrame {
Framer(){
    int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 200;
    int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 140;
    this.setSize(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("D&Dice");
    JButton display = new JButton("0");
    display.setEnabled(false);
    this.add(display, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}
}

public class DandDice extends Framer {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Buttoner panel = new Buttoner();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2));
    Framer ramka = new Framer();
   ramka.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

}
```

And I'd like to get acess to for example d4 in DandDice class

Comment: provide a method in your Buttoner class that allows that

Comment: Can you please give me sample?

Comment: are you familiar with the concept of setters and getters, or any other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not related to your question but:

```
Buttoner panel = new Buttoner();
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2));
```

The layout manager of the panel should be set BEFORE you add the buttons to the panel.

That logic belongs in the constructor of your Buttoner class.

> how can i get access to my buttons outside of their own class:

Not sure why you would want to do that.

The JFrame is just a container to hold the child components. You should not have any application logic in the class that creates the frame.

Comment: Becouse i'd like to make action for every buttton using actionPerformed but i cant use .getSource, couse actionPerformed does not see my buttons

Comment: @Mr.Orange, The ActionListener should be defined in the class where you create the button and add the button to the panel. This can be done by using inner classes, annoymous inner classes or lambdas.